# Convertir de valor Decimal a DateTime

Tags: c#

Obtengo valores de mi DataTable desde la base de datos, y los datos que obtengo son en decimales ejemplo (20160901) que en este caso seria 01 de Septiembre del 2016 pero no puedo convertirlo a formato fecha con el metodo Convert.ToDateTime();

Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Adjunto parte del código:

```
  DateTime iDateInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["DESC"].ToString());
  DateTime iDateFin = DateTime.Now;
```

//Aqui obtengo la data

```
            for (DateTime dt = iDateInicio; dt <= iDateFin; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
            {
                if (iMesBandera != dt.Month)
                {
                    iHeaderFinal = iii - 1;
                    e.HeaderRange[Helper.GetColumnNameNew(iHeaderInicial).ToString() + "8:" + Helper.GetColumnNameNew(iHeaderFinal).ToString() + "8"].Cells.Merge();
                    iHeaderInicial = iii;
                    iMesBandera = dt.Month;
                }
                iii++;
            }
```

//esta es la funcionalidad de mi recorrido.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código que hiciste? Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) o [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx). En tu caso,sería algo asi:

```
DateTime iDateInicio = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["DESC"].ToString(), 
                                       "yyyyMMdd",
                                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

De todas maneras, si puedes modificar la estructura de la base de datos, lo mejor es tiempre almacenar las fechas como `DateTime`. no tiene mucho sentido utilizar un tipo de datos numérico.

Comment: Gracias, lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera.                          var valor = Convert.ToString(iValorBandera.Substring(6, 2) + "/" + iValorBandera.Substring(4, 2) + "/" + iValorBandera.Substring(0, 4));
                        var data = DateTime.ParseExact(valor + " 12:00:00 AM", "M/d/yyyy 12:mm:ss tt", null); y si desde la base de datos esta modificado porque lo necesitaba para usarlo como ID. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

También puedes calcular desde el valor numérico el año, mes y dia:

```
 var iDateInicio = new DateTime(n/10000, (n/100)%100, n %100)
```